# I want to show images in paragraph but when i click to show images then text is moving up and down

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a paragraph I want to show images in the paragraph over some words like a horse, cloud, etc. The problem is this when I show images over words in a paragraph then words and lines move up and down but I want when I click on the button for showing images then paragraph lines and text should be fixed not move up and down.

```
<div class="member-detail-wrap" id="story_div"  ontouchstart="showImage()"  ontouchend="hideImage()">                                       

<div class="sqs-block-content">
 <p id="story">
   Charlie was so used to all his toys and various stuff, that he began to want something different. 
   One of his uncles found a fine <span class="horse"> horse </span> and he gave it to Charlie, as something unusual. 
   Charlie was very excited at having a <span class="horse2">horse </span>. He learned to ride, and was constantly on his horse, around the <span class='farm'> farm </span>.

   However, he treated the horse just as badly as he did all his other toys, 
   and it soon started looking neglected and sick. For the first time in his life Charlie became truly worried. 
   He loved the horse, and the fact that his family had offered to swap it for a new one meant nothing to him.
  </p>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
function showImage()
{
    $('.horse').html('<span class="horse"> horse </span>').fadeIn();
      $('.horse2').html('<span class="horse2"> horse </span>').fadeIn();
      $('.farm').html('<span class="farm"> farm </span>').fadeIn();

    $('.horse').html('<img src="stories/hourse.jpeg" width="55" height="53">');
      $('.horse2').html('<img src="stories/hourse.jpeg" width="60" height="53">');
      $('.farm').html('<img src="stories/farm.jpg" width="50">');
}
function hideImage()
{
    $('.horse').fadeOut(1500);
    $('.horse2').fadeOut(1500);
    $('.farm').fadeOut(1500);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.horse').html('<span class="horse"> horse </span>').fadeIn();
    $('.horse2').html('<span class="horse2"> horse </span>').fadeIn();
    $('.farm').html('<span class="farm"> farm </span>').fadeIn();
  },1500)

}
</script>
```

Screenshot of the paragraph.

[image]

Comment: Your closing `</script>` tag is misspelled as `</sctipt>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a pure CSS solution?

Add the images as `before` pseudo elements and center them on top of the words. Make them invisible by default, but transition them into view when the `story_div` is active.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/537Lkes1/28/) incase the snippet below doesn't work.

```css
.pic {
  position: relative;
}

.pic:before {
  content: '';

  /* center */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /* scale */
  background-size: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

  /* hide */
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 1.5s ease, opacity 1.5s ease;
}

#story_div:active .pic:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.pic.horse:before {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50');
}

.pic.farm:before {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50');
}
```

```html
<div id="story_div" class="member-detail-wrap">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <p id="story">
      Charlie was so used to all his toys and various stuff, that he began to want something different.
      One of his uncles found a fine <span class="pic horse">horse</span> and he gave it to Charlie, as something unusual.
      Charlie was very excited at having a <span class="pic horse">horse</span>. He learned to ride, and was constantly on his horse, around the <span class='pic farm'>farm</span>.

      However, he treated the horse just as badly as he did all his other toys,
      and it soon started looking neglected and sick. For the first time in his life Charlie became truly worried.
      He loved the horse, and the fact that his family had offered to swap it for a new one meant nothing to him.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can put your images in `before` pseudoelement added to each `horse` and `farm` classes. SCSS code below, you will have to play a little bit with positioning of images, but that should do the trick for you.

```
.horse {
  position: relative;

  &.displayImage {
   &:before {
     content:url('stories/hourse.jpeg');
     width: 55px;
     height: 53px;
     position: absolute;
     top: -10px // or any other value that would move image above text line
   }
  }
 }
```

and small change to JS code below. I replaced `showImage` and `hideImage` function with one which would do the trick- there was no point in having two separate functions, one responsible for adding classes, another for removing them.

```
function toggleImage() {
   $('.horse, .horse2, .farm').toggleClass('displayImage');
}
```

Of course, you will have to change HTML as well:

```
<div class="member-detail-wrap" id="story_div"  ontouchstart="toggleImage()"  ontouchend="toggleImage()">
```

I hope that helps and I understood your problem correctly :)

Comment: JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4w3t0bk5/3/ I had to replace `ontouchstart` with `onclick` function but it shows how it works